# On the properties of Dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $G=D_{2n}$ be a dihedral group of order $2n$, where $n$ is even. We know in this case $|Z(D_{2n})|=2$. I need an idea for a proof of the fact $D_{2n}/Z(D_{2n}) \cong D_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your group is generated by a rotation $\sigma$ and a reflection $\tau$, the homomorphism that maps $\sigma$ to $\sigma^2$ and fixes $\tau$ has kernel $Z$ and the required image.

Comment: may i ask you write the kernel of this homomorphism please?

Comment: because n is even, say n = 2k, the non-trivial element in the kernel is $\sigma^k$, your central element.

Comment: Ok thanks dearr Freiburghaus